# hdl verilog Compiler Errors

Tags: verilog

When I first tried to compile my code, I only had syntax errors and was able to fix them. Now I have errors that I cannot figure out at all. I don't know how to fix.

Here is my current code:

```
module p_5 (output y_out, input x_in, clk, reset_b);
    parameter s_a = 2'd0;
    parameter s_b = 2'd1;
    parameter s_c = 2'd2;

    reg Set_flag;
    reg Clr_flag;
    reg [1:0] state, next_state;
    assign y_out = (state == s_b) || (state == s_c) ;
    always @ (posedge clk)
     if (reset_b == 1'b0) state <= s_a;
     else state <= next_state;

    always @ (state, x_in, flag) begin
     next_state = s_a;
     Set_flag = 0;
     Clr_flag = 0;
     case (state)
         s_a: if ((x_in == 1'b1) && (flag == 1'b0))
            begin next_state = s_a; Set_flag = 1; end
            else if ((x_in == 1'b1) && (flag == 1'b1))
            begin next_state = s_b; Set_flag = 0; end 
            else if (x_in == 1'b0) next_state = s_a;
         s_b: if (x_in == 1'b0) next_state = s_b;
            else begin next_state = s_c; Clr_flag = 1; end
         s_c: if (x_in == 1'b0) next_state = s_c;
            else next_state = s_a;
         default: begin next_state = s_a; Clr_flag = 1'b0; Set_flag = 1'b0; end
      endcase
end

always @ (posedge clk)
    if (reset_b == 1'b0) flag <= 0;
    else if (Set_flag) flag <= 1'b1;
    else if (Clr_flag) flag <= 1'b0;
endmodule
```

This is the test bench:

```
module test_5 ();
    wire y_out;
    reg x_in, clk, flag, reset_b;

    p_5 M0 (y_out, x_in, clk, reset_b);

    initial #500 $finish;
    initial begin clk = 0; forever #5 clk = !clk; end
    initial fork
            reset_b = 1'b0;
            #20 reset_b = 1;
            #20 x_in = 1'b0;
            #40 x_in = 1'b1;
            #50 x_in = 1'b0;
            #80 x_in = 1'b1;
            #100 x_in = 0;
            #150 x_in = 1'b1;
            #160 x_in = 1'b0;
            #200 x_in = 1'b1;
            #230 reset_b = 1'b0;
            #250 reset_b = 1'b1;
            #300 x_in = 1'b0;
            #300 flag = 1'b0;
    join
endmodule
```

Errors:

```
p5.v:22: error: Unable to bind wire/reg/memory `flag' in `t_ques_5_50.M0'
p5.v:22: error: Unable to elaborate condition expression.
p5.v:17: error: Unable to bind wire/reg/memory `flag' in `t_ques_5_50.M0'
flag
p5.v:36: error: Could not find variable ``flag'' in ``t_ques_5_50.M0''
p5.v:37: error: Could not find variable ``flag'' in ``t_ques_5_50.M0''
p5.v:38: error: Could not find variable ``flag'' in ``t_ques_5_50.M0''
7 error(s) during elaboration.
```

Answer (score 2):

You refer to the value `flag` repeatedly inside p5.v, yet it is not declared anywhere as an input, reg, or wire.

Add the appropriate declaration and it should be resolved.